# Returned array evaluated later from async Firestore calls doesn't update in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

It seems "images" array is first empty and the elements are added later when data is fetched from firestore - but the React state won't update, so no image is displayed, although I used await everywhere possible.

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function getAllImages() {
      const images = await imageStorage.downloadAllImages(true);
// images is first empty and then populated after the html has been rendered
      setImages(images);
    }
   
      getAllImages();
    
  }, []);
```

display images:

```
const handleGetImages = (images) => {
    console.log("images", images); // image is first empty and then populated after the html has been rendered
    return images.map((imageData) => {
      return (
        <Grid.Column key={imageData.url}>
          <span class="image left">
            <img src={imageData.url} style={styles.image} alt="" />
          </span>
        </Grid.Column>
      );
    });
  };
```

imageStorage.js

```
export async function downloadAllImages(thumbnail) {
  const imageRef = collection(db, "images");
  console.log("hi");
  var images = [];

  const q = query(imageRef, orderBy("date", "desc"), limit(10));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

  querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
    var imagePath = doc.data().ref; // image/task/...
    if (thumbnail) imagePath = imagePath.replace("images", "thumbnails");
    // GET metadata of the image
    const imageRef = ref(storage, imagePath);

    // GET [imagePrefix] URL
    const url = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);
    const fullMetadata = await getMetadata(imageRef);

    images.push({
      path: imagePath,
      url: url,
      metadata: fullMetadata.customMetadata,
    });
  });

  return images;
}
```

Any way to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is close. `Array.prototype.forEach` is synchronous though. I suspect your `downloadAllImages` function isn't waiting for the loop callbacks to complete and returns the `images` array not populated yet.

Refactor the logic to create an array of Promises (*the `async` callback functions*) and await `Promise.all` them, then you'll have a populated array of images to return.

```
export async function downloadAllImages(thumbnail) {
  const imageRef = collection(db, "images");

  const q = query(imageRef, orderBy("date", "desc"), limit(10));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

  // Map querySnapshot docs to array of async functions (Promises)
  const imageRequests = querySnapshot.docs.map(async (doc) => {
    const imagePath = doc.data().ref; // image/task/...
    if (thumbnail) imagePath = imagePath.replace("images", "thumbnails");
    // GET metadata of the image
    const imageRef = ref(storage, imagePath);

    // GET [imagePrefix] URL
    const url = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);
    const fullMetadata = await getMetadata(imageRef);

    // Return image objects
    return {
      path: imagePath,
      url: url,
      metadata: fullMetadata.customMetadata,
    };
  });

  // Return array of resolved promises (i.e. the image objects)
  return Promise.all(imageRequests);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent so long on this haha it worked perfectly! Just one thing, it says querySnapshot.map is not a function, think it should`querySnapshot.docs.map(...)`.

Comment: @guckmalmensch Thanks, updated my answer to reflect that.